# How do I properly check whether a struct field implements an interface when it requires a pointer receiver?

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to determine if a field on a `struct` implements a given interface that has a pointer receiver.

I have a [go playground setup with my confusion](https://play.golang.org/p/eRUQ8EGo2-E).

Say I have the following `interface`:

```golang
type Stringee interface {
    FromString(s string) error
}
```

With an enum implementing it:

```golang
type Enum int

const (
    EnumUnknown Enum = iota
    EnumA
    EnumB
)

func (my *Enum) String() string { return enumToStr[*my] }

func (my *Enum) FromString(s string) error {
    if v, ok := enumFromStr[s]; ok {
        *my = v
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("invalid value")
}

var enumToStr = map[Enum]string{
    EnumA: "A",
    EnumB: "B",
}
var enumFromStr = func() map[string]Enum {
    m := make(map[string]Enum)
    for k, v := range enumToStr {
        m[v] = k
    }
    return m
}()
```

I first get the `Type` of the `interface`:

```golang
var stringeeType = reflect.TypeOf(new(Stringee)).Elem()
```

then I can perform checks against it:

```golang
e := EnumA
e.FromString("B")
e.String() // "B"


reflect.ValueOf(e).Type().Implements(stringeeType) // false
reflect.ValueOf(&e).Type().Implements(stringeeType) // true
```

Which is to be expected. However, what I don't know how to do is perform the check as a pointer if type is a field of a `struct`. For example:

Say I have the following `struct`:

```golang
type Struct struct {
    E Enum
}
```

How do I check to see whether or not `E` implements the `interface` `Stringee`?

```golang
t := Struct{}
tv := reflect.ValueOf(&t)
fieldE := tv.Elem().Field(0)

fieldE.Type().Implements(stringeeType) // false
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eRUQ8EGo2-E

Comment: If the field is addressable, then take the address of the field and check that value: `if fieldE.CannAddr() { fmt.Println("&T.E implements Stringee", fieldE.Addr().Type().Implements(stringeeType))}`

Comment: @iLoveReflection hah, yea. that was it, thank you. I'm not sure what I tried taking the `Addr()` of earlier but it clearly wasn't right. Now I just need to figure out why https://github.com/chanced/labeler/blob/master/unmarshalers.go#L103 blows up on me even though there's a guard above.

Comment: @iLoveReflection anyway, please post an answer with that and I'll mark the question as resolved with your reply. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chance where is the "guard" in the returned function? You're aware the returned function's argument `r` overwrites the closure's `r`, therefore the former isn't checked for `CanInterface` and `Implements`, right?

Comment: @Chance unless `unmarshalLabelee` and the function it returns are guaranteed to be always invoked with the same `r` there's no guard really, and the `CanInterface` & `Implements` check seems wasted.

Comment: @mkopriva the guards are in the wrapping func (the wrapping funcs determine which func to return)... it's convoluted, I know.

Comment: @mkopriva this is my first project in Go. I'm trying to push the weight of the reflection onto the initialization because the initialization is handled in goroutines per field. The structure can also potentially be memoized later. By the time a func is selected and assigned, it is presumed to be the "right fit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is addressable, then take the address of the field and check that value:

```
if fieldE.CannAddr() { 
    impl := fieldE.Addr().Type().Implements(stringeeType)
    fmt.Println("&T.E implements Stringee", impl)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you have only the `reflect.Type` not the `relect.Value`, for example when checking if a struct's field implements an interface, you can use `reflect.PtrTo` for this.

This func will check if any field of the given struct implements `Stringee`:

```
func CheckFields(s interface{}) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        field := rt.Field(i)
        ptr := reflect.PtrTo(field.Type)
        if ptr.Implements(stringeeType) {
            fmt.Println(field.Name + " implements Stringee")
        }
    }
}

type Test struct {
    Field  int
    Field2 MyTypeWithStringee
}

test := Test{}

CheckFields(test)
```